# How do I preserve or transfer the old project settings in an iOS app to a totally new project?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swiftui

I have an iOS app written using storyboards and I and want to convert to SwiftUI with a totally new project. How do I preserve or transfer the project settings from the old project to the new project?

Comment: what do you mean with project settings? Userdefaults? or really XCode Project settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible way:

1. Backup current project folder (just in case, archive & store somewhere separately)
2. Duplicate project folder & rename it
3. From duplicated folder open `.xcodeproj` (non needed to rename)
4. In Project Navigator click project

4a. (keep project-wide-only settings). In target section select all targets and 
click `-` button at bottom pane (or press Delete key on keyboard)

4b. (keep per-target settings). Select every target > Build Phases tab > Remove everything in every section.